# Packages are not found

Tags: ubuntu, compilation

I am trying to compile MC2 server's c++ code on ubuntu10.10. on configuring it i get the following error:

```
sonal@vlab:~/Downloads/wayfinder-Wayfinder-Server-fbd75c3$ ./waf configure
Checking for program g++                 : not found 
Checking for program c++                 : not found 
Checking for program icpc                : not found 
Checking for program c++                 : not found 
Checking for program CC                  : not found 
Checking for program tex                 : not found 
Checking for program latex               : not found 
Checking for program pdflatex            : not found 
Checking for program bibtex              : not found 
Checking for program dvips               : not found 
Checking for program dvipdf              : ok /usr/bin/dvipdf 
Checking for program ps2pdf              : ok /usr/bin/ps2pdf 
Checking for program makeindex           : not found 
Checking for program pdf2ps              : ok /usr/bin/pdf2ps 
Checking for openssl                     : ok 
Checking for cairo                       : not found 
Checking for ImageMagick                 : not found 
Checking for librsvg-2.0                 : not found 
Checking for program mysql_config        : not found 
sh: mysql_config: not found
sh: mysql_config: not found
Checking for libmemcached                : not found 
Checking for gtk+-2.0 >= 2.1.0           : Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found 

error: the configuration failed (see '/home/sonal/Downloads/wayfinder-Wayfinder-Server-fbd75c3/output/config.log')
```

even though most of these packages are already installed.

Comment: Should be on http://askubuntu.com/.

Answer (score 1):

try installing the essentials first:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

then to install other stuff you can use:

```
sudo apt-get install PackageName
```

example:

```
sudo apt-get install ImageMagick
```